# How to share a clipboard between PC and windows phone 8.1

Tags: sync

I need to sync and share data real-time between this two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **there's no direct clipboard synchronization between PC and phone** (e.g. you press Ctrl+C on PC and you can immediately paste it from clipboard on phone).

However, there's an app which may help you, [SkyType](https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/store/p/skytype/9nblggh07pkm). You can easily copy-paste text between phone and connected device.